# Is it possible to represent binary logic gates by plotting Bezier curves?

Tags: logic

Is it possible to represent a basic set of logic gates (AND, NAND, OR, NOR, EX-OR, and EX-NOR) in any other 2D chart type than a table if we allow some "flexibility", and not using the regular electrical diagrams?

For example, if we take the AND logic...

```
INPUT A  |  INPUT B  |  OUTPUT
------------------------------
    0    |     0     |    0
    1    |     0     |    0
    0    |     1     |    0
    1    |     1     |    1
```

... and convert the binary 0 and 1 into a decimal version, so 0.00 through to 1.00, (assuming the 0.51 is the trigger level that would denote a binary 1 when translated back) could we draw a chart like this where any value above the red line in blue is considered to be an AND.

[link to AND chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyO1z.jpg)

Ideally I'd like to use Bezier curves or vectors and spaces, but not limited to this, interested to know if there are other options.

Comment: The question is a little vague. Is each chart a single function identified by a label, or is there a single chart and the function is determined by the charge levels?

Comment: Digital signals are essentially analogue if you are able to measure different charge levels, rather than charged and no-charge. Is that what you mean by decimal? Otherwise, for a single function, the 2D chart you demonstrated can be satisfied with binary values.

Comment: I suspect this question properly belongs on https://cs.stackexchange.com/